# “Try It” URL has wrong URI

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, api-v2.2, documentation

On API doc pages, the “link” link at the top-right of the “Try It” sections presents a URL with the wrong domain name:

[image: "Try it" HUD]

For example, on [docs/similar](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/similar), the URL displayed will be:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/similar#order=desc&sort=relevance&title=how%20do%20i%20get%20all%20sections&filter=default&site=craftcms
```

but it should be

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/similar?order=desc&sort=relevance&title=how%20do%20i%20get%20all%20sections&site=craftcms
```

(URI begins with `docs/` instead of `2.2/`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link is correct.  The purpose of that control is to provide a URL to the doc page with all the parameters prefilled.  This is what most users expect and is similar to how that link control works on the rest of Stack Exchange.

To get a direct link to the API, click on the link next to the *Run* button:

[image: Doc page links]

This has a URL like:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/similar?order=desc&sort=activity&title=blah&site=stackoverflow
```

---

Note that the value in the browser's address bar *can* be very similar to the *link* control's URL, except:

- The address bar only updates when the *Run* button is pressed, the *link* control updates whenever a parameter is changed.
- The address bar will then also contain the `&run=true` parameter -- which can sometimes be undesirable from a simplicity, economy, and length perspective.